# Google Maps API v2 for Android - Let user add marker or overlay of specific things they spotted

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

Thanks for reading this.  I've just implemented the Google Maps API in my Android APP and it works perfectly.  I've added markers of specific points of interest in the onCreate which also works fine.  The next thing I need to do is give the user of the app the ability to add a marker or overlay if they see something on the route an this should be visible to all the other users using the app.  The App is used to help people spot animals in a nature reserve by checking the app to see where animals was spotted by other users of the app.  If possible i need these markers to disappear after let's say 2 hours as the animal will probably not be there anymore.  My "setMyLocation is set to true and the app shows my current possition.  Please help point me in the right direction as I'm not sure where to start or what to use for this.  Your help is appreciated.

Thanks
Janno

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

Save the positions in a database. Add a colum timestamp to the table. In this timestamp you save the current time + 2 hours.

To get the right positions, Create a query which selects the positions where the timestamp is bigger than the current time.

It might be a nice idea to save what animal it is.

Good luck

Comment: Hi Robin.  Thanks for the reply.  I haven't used a db before in an app.  Will read up on it and see what I can do.  What should I use to show the pins or markers on the map? Overlays??

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without a database??

Comment: You said you wanted the marker to be visible to all the other users. So I guess to upload the marker to some server right?